# Multiple windings on single ferrite ring vs multiple ferrite rings

Tags: ferrite-bead, ferrite

My question is does putting cables through multiple identical ferrite rings the same as winding them multiple times on a single ferrite ring?

I have my current setup as follows with multiple ferrite rings.
[image: ferrite rings on cables]

Answer (score 2):

Multiple turns increase the flux density in the core by a factor of N and increases the inductance by a factor of \$N^2\$.

Increasing the number of cores increases the inductance by a factor of n, while leaving the flux density in each core the same.

This the energy stored in the field without saturating the core is a constant per number of cores.

You appear to have a common-mode choke arrangement, so it is vital that all the wires go through each core the same number of turns. Running (say) one wire through each core would be a far less effective use of the cores.

Answer (score 0):

If you run multiple wires through the same ferrite there could be additional cross-talk between cables (the cables are closer together and get stronger inductive coupling) vs running one wire through one ferrite three times. With a single ferrite, the magnetic field around the wire couples to the ferrite better.

I would think that the differences wouldn't be that much and most likely within 10% of each other, but there isn't a good way to know without testing or doing some complex hand calculations with all the dimensions of the wire and material properties of the ferrite.

If your having and issue with noise, then you may want to consider a better scheme.